# Make Chrome play m4v files instead of download them

Tags: google-chrome, mp4

When I go here:  https://midstateems.org/blog/meetings/  (my website)

1) Firefox plays the video in the browser

2) Chrome downloads the m4v file

How do I make Chrome play the m4v file, like Firefox does.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Its a server side configuration. You must return the correct mime type.

Comment: @szatmary can you explain *how* to do that? And why FF plays them in-browser but Chrome doesn't? That would have all the makings of an answer :)

Comment: No I can’t explain how to change the mime type in your server config, because I don’t even know which Http server software it is running on. You didn’t include that information in the question.

Comment: I am running on Dreamhost hosting. 
It’s Apache with Ubuntu
https://midstateems.org/blog/meetings/